# How to fit my Layout to any Screen in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

I'm building my own application game for Android, it's a Tic Tac Toe game.
my activities contains mostly *ImageViews* , all the images placed in the dir ***res\drawable-mdpi*** ONLY.
the rest of the drawable folders are empty.

my problem is that when i run the app on a **5.4 inch** MDPI screen it works fine and it looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK3jo.jpg]

but when i run the app on another screen of different size for example this **4.65 inch** XHDPI screen, it looks like this:

[image]

in the above activity i used *LinearLayout* and *RelativeLayout*, what should i do to fit my layout to any screen ?

thanks

- thanks for editting the pictures

this is the code of the xml file of activity_board.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/board_page_bg"
android:gravity="center" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/players_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/playersName"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/players_score"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/playersPoints"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/machines_score"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="172dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/machinePoints"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/machines_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:onClick="openChat"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/machineName"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_1_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_2_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_3_empty" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_4_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_5_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_6_empty" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_7_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_8_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="315dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_9_empty" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
                    android:text="@string/gameNumber"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/count_down"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="390dp"
                    android:text="@string/countDown"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/end_game"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/EndGame"
            android:onClick="endGame"
            android:src="@drawable/endgame_btn_1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you are using hardcoded widht and height values using `dp` etc.. start using values like `wrap_content`, `fill_parent`etc.
use weights in case of linear layouts. 
These values takes care of resizing according to different screens.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i added the xml file of the activity, please take a look

Comment: check out this link too :- http://developer.android.com/training/best-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a `drawable` folder, just the word "drawable", in `res` and put your game images in there. That will make the game images the same across every device density.

Without looking at your XML, I would agree that you're probably using hardcoded `dp` values instead of sizing the layout with math, ie, weights, `match_parent`, `alignParentRight`, etc.

I have adjusted your XML to be easier. I did not plug it into a previewer or anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/board_page_bg"
android:gravity="center" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="ADJUST ME"
        android:layout_marginRight="ADJUST ME"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Scoreboard -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/players_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/playersName"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/players_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/players_name"
                android:text="@string/playersPoints"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/machines_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="172dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/machines_name"
                android:text="@string/machinePoints"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/machines_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:onClick="openChat"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/machineName"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_1_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_2_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_3_empty" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_4_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_5_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_6_empty" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_7_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_8_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_9_empty" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="ADJUST ME" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/game_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/gameNumber"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count_down"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/countDown"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/end_game"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/EndGame"
            android:onClick="endGame"
            android:src="@drawable/endgame_btn_1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i will try doing the drawable folder as you said, but please also take a look at the code i've added, it's all using `wrap_content` and `match_parent` thanks

Comment: See my edit. I removed a lot of junk from it that wasn't necessary. It comes in three main parts: The scoreboard, the game board, and the game and countdown area. This probably won't fit exactly, but it's definitely better. The design is somewhat flawed, since the background image is a majority of the graphics, so the background is going to stretch on different aspect ratios. I would suggest you break up the background into pieces.

Comment: i created folders `drawable-xxxhdpi` , `drawable-xxhdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, and the rest, and i used a software called `9Patch resizer` to change my `mdpi (default pictures to xxxhdpi)` , the red `BUTTONS` resized fine, but in the board activity the board (it's an image) resized fine but it still stretched when i run in on my `xxxhdpi` phone like in the picture... i am trying your code now , i dont know what did you mean by `ADJUST ME` at the first LinearLayout, but i will try removing that two attributes..

Comment: Adjust me means you have to put in your own numbers and make them look nice. Xxxhdpi is currently a very unpopular resolution and it is easy to ignore.

Comment: it still does not work, i can not control the images and the fonts in this specific activity, also with your xml code that you changed still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RelativeLayout?

You should 
1. use RelativeLayout as the base container
2. put the "Player" and "System" score inside the same horizontal LinearLayout so that they won't overlap
3. Put the "End game" button as an element which align parent bottom

The screenshots you attached shows that it's a problem caused by the soft status bar. RelativeLayout would help and you should try to prevent hard-coding the dimensions in numbers but making the auto-adjust in RelativeLayout using margins, "layout_toLeftOf", "layout_toRightOf" and etc.

Comment: i think that is what i did, please take a look at the XML code i've added. thanks :)

Comment: for example, the block1, block2 and block3 are not related, but in fact block2 should be toRightOf block1