# RelativeLayout inside LinearLayout is not shown perfectly

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I am following my previois question: [How to fit my Layout to any Screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370757/how-to-fit-my-layout-to-any-screen-in-android/27371178?noredirect=1#comment43387493_27371178)

in my activity I have a `LinearLayout` and inside it bunch of `RelativeLayouts`
the `LinearLayout` which has the background of the `Board` is set to be in the center and inside it all the `RelativeLayout` and the `ImageViews` of the Blocks.

the `LinearLayout` is a vertical Layout of three parts of `RelativeLayouts`:

1. name and score
2. 9 x-o blocks
3. game number and countdown

I converted all my pictures of my `MDPI` using `9Patch Resizer Software` and saved all in `XXXHDPI` (which is the current phone I am running at)

when I run the activity on my LG G3 phone which is (`XXXHDPI`) , all other activites work just fine except this activity in this picture below:

[image]

instead of being in the center and all the `ImageViews` ordered to be on each of the 9 white spaces, the background of the `LinearLayout` is stretched to the width of the screen and the Blocks are all over the place .

but when I remove all the `RelativeLayouts` from inside the `LinearLayout` , the board background of the `LinearLayout` is shown perfectly in the center, which means the conversion of the images to `XXXHDPI` is fine.

(just to mention that in the `MDPI Emulator` it looks perfect as in this picture: )

[image]

this is my Activity XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toplogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logottt" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/players_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/playersName"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/players_score"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/playersPoints"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/machines_score"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="172dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/machinePoints"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/machines_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="openChat"
                    android:text="@string/machineName"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_1_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_2_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_3_empty" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_4_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_5_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_6_empty" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_7_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_8_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/block9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="315dp"
                android:onClick="touch"
                android:src="@drawable/block_9_empty" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
                    android:text="@string/gameNumber"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/count_down"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="390dp"
                    android:text="@string/countDown"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/end_game"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/EndGame"
            android:onClick="endGame"
            android:src="@drawable/endgame_btn_1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have a lot of RelativeLayouts with only a TextView inside. Please remove those RelativeLayouts, since they don't do anything extra and make the code more complicated. So replace <RelativeLayout><TextView/></RelativeLayout> by <TextView/> please, and after that I will be able to help you better. Also your root tag, RelativeLayout, has only one child: LinearLayout. The outer RelativeLayout is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey , i figured a long way to deal with density of device,

```
density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

and if density equal 4 which means xxxhdpi then to run the xml of the xxxhdpi

```
if (density == 4) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_board_xxxhdpi);
            }
```

thank you all for your help